# Can you please give me a update table statement for my Merge statement on ORACLE database

Tags: sql, oracle

```
merge into TableA a
USING TableB  b  
ON (b.name_ID = a.name_id and b.place = a.place
 and b.city=a.city)  
when matched then update set a.status = b.status ,
a.updatedatetime = timestamp 
where address is  null;
```

Can you please give a update statement for the above merge statement

Comment: This is called "updating a join". Oracle only permits this if you have a unique or primary key index in TableB on NAME_ID and PLACE. Do you have such an index? Also, which table contains the ADDRESS column and which table contains the TIMESTAMP column? Also, TIMESTAMP is a very bad name for a column because it is a reserved word.

Comment: HI Stew,Thanks for the reply.I have indexes on tableb on name id and place.Address column is of table a.Timestamp means here it is systimestamp.It was a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your MERGE. In order to have an updateable join, tableb must be a "key-preserved table". That means you have to have one of the following: - a primary key constraint on (name_id, place, city) in any order; - a unique constraint on those columns in any order; - or a UNIQUE index on those three columns.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below -

```
UPDATE TableA a
   SET (a.status, a.updatedatetime) = (SELECT b.status, timestamp
                                         FROM TableB b
                                        WHERE b.name_ID = a.name_id
                                          AND b.place = a.place
                                          AND b.city=a.city)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM TableB b
                WHERE b.name_ID = a.name_id
                  AND b.place = a.place
                  AND b.city=a.city) 
   AND address IS NULL;
```

Comment: Well, that's invalid. WHERE (SELECT ...) --> what?

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this:

```
update tablea a set
  (a.status, a.updatedatetime) = 
  (Select b.status, timestamp
   from tableb b
   where b.name_id = a.name_id
     and b.place = a.place
     and b.city = a.city
  )
where a.address is null;
```

---

Additionally, you might want/need to add another condition (`exists`) in order not to update rows you didn't mean to:

```
...
where a.address is null
  --
  and exists (select null
              from tableb c
              where c.name_id = a.name_id
                and c.place = a.place
                and c.city = a.city
             );
```